# "Prepararsi a un esame" oppure "prepararsi un esame"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, verbs

Quale tra queste due è la forma corretta?

> - Prepararsi a un esame"

oppure

> - Prepararsi (o preparare) un esame.

Cercando su Google ho trovato esempi di entrambe le forme.

Comment: "Prepararsi per un esame". Ciao!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direi che tutte possono essere corrette. Quella che suona un po' strana effettivamente è "Prepararsi un esame".
Diciamo che così le userei:

- Prepararsi mentalmente ad un esame / Prepararsi mentalmente per un esame
- Preparare un esame studiando a fondo le materie

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Grazie, è un piacere aiutare gli altri a conoscere meglio la mia bellissima lingua.